# Interface Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\CoreBundle\Translatable\TranslatableInterface does not exist

Tags: symfony, translate

I'm new in symfony, I install and active sonata translate, but when I try go to admin dashboard, I have error:

Interface Symfony\Cmf\Bundle\CoreBundle\Translatable\TranslatableInterface does not exist

Comment: Set locale to EN in config ?

Answer (score 3):

Just disable `phpcr`

```
sonata_translation:
    ------------------
    phpcr:
        enabled: false
```